# Inject methods into existing classes

Tags: scala

I want to come out a way to define a new method in some existing class in scala.

For example, I think the `asInstanceOf[T]` method has too long a name, I want to replace it with `as[T].`

A straight forward approach can be:

```
class WrappedAny(val a: Any) {
  def as[T] = a.asInstanceOf[T]
}

implicit def wrappingAny(a: Any): WrappedAny = new WrappedAny(a)
```

Is there a more natural way with less code?

Also, a strange thing happens when I try this:

```
scala> class A

defined class A

scala> implicit def toA(x: Any): A = x

toA: (x: Any)A

scala> toA(1)
```

And the console hang. It seems that `toA(Any)` should not pass the type checking phase, and it can't when it's not implicit. And putting all the code into a external source code can produce the same problem. How did this happen? Is it a bug of the compiler(version 2.8.0)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing technically wrong with your approach to pimping `Any`, although I think it's generally ill-advised. Likewise, there's a reason `asInstanceOf` and `isInstanceOf` are so verbosely named; it's to discourage you from using them! There's almost certainly a better, statically type-safe way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Regarding the example which causes your console to hang: the declared type of `toA` is `Any => A`, yet you've defined its result as `x`, which has type `Any`, not `A`. How can this possibly compile? Well, remember that when an apparent type error occurs, the compiler looks around for any available implicit conversions to resolve the problem. In this case, it needs an implicit conversion `Any => A`... and finds one: `toA`! So the reason `toA` type checks is because the compiler is implicitly redefining it as:

```
implicit def toA(x: Any): A = toA(x)
```

... which of course results in infinite recursion when you try to use it.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing. How did you came up with this idea? And moreover, the asInstanceOf[T] is just an example. I'm just curious that is there any syntax candy to work in the general case.

Comment: As a general rule, if there is obviously a type error in your code but the compiler accepts it, there's an implicit conversion at work... that and the fact that it was hanging were the major clues :)

Answer (score 3):

In your second example you are passing `Any` to a function that must return `A`. However it never returns `A` but the same `Any` you passed in. The compiler then tries to apply the implicit conversion which in turn does not return an `A` but `Any`, and so on.

If you define toA as not being implicit you get:

```
scala> def toA(x: Any): A = x           
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: A
       def toA(x: Any): A = x
                            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, this has been discussed on Scala lists before. The pimp my class pattern is indeed a bit verbose for what it does, and, perhaps, there might be a way to clean the syntax without introducing new keywords.

The bit about new keywords is that one of Scala goals is to make the language scalable through libraries, instead of turning the language into a giant quilt of ideas that passed someone's criteria for "useful enough to add to the language" and, at the same time, making other ideas impossible because they weren't deemed useful and/or common enough.

Anyway, nothing so far has come up, and I haven't heard that there is any work in progress towards that goal. You are welcome to join the community through its mailing lists and contribute to its development.