# how to add method to standard java class

Tags: java, class, methods, monkeypatching

Is there a way to add a method to a standard Java class, such as `Object`?

I know you can't subclass classes like `String` which are final, but `Object` isn't.  I know I could just subclass Object and define a method in the subclass and make all my classes subclasses of that, but I'd rather not have to do that.

I suspect that this is either impossible or I've overlooked something.  Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: You can't add method to standard java class.

Comment: Well you should do that! The behaviour you are expecting is in Javascript prototypes.

Comment: Is this for testing or production code?

Comment: Could you explain why you'd possibly want to do this?

Comment: Yes I imamgined it was impossible in Java.  Initially it is for doing some experiments but if I can get other stuff to go with it to work it would hopefully end up in some OSS software.  There are really two reasons I was hoping to add a method to Object.  One is because logically it is the best way for other reasons.  The other reason is that the method(s) I have in mind crucially rely on the this keyword.  However, see below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this in Java. But other JVM languages are capable of doing so:

- in [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) [`ExpandoMetaClass`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) allows adding arbitrary methods to any class
- in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) implicit conversions can be used to emulate such behaviour in statically-typed manner, see: [Inject methods into existing classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213239)
- also you can run [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) ([jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby)) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) on top of JVM

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes I thought one of the JVM scripting languages might be able to do it.  This is acceptable to me.  What I should have said is that I wanted a JVM solution (not necessarily Java) so one of the dynamic JVM languages or using reflect or even using a customised Object class file in the classpath would be okay.  I'll look at groovy and javascript for sure.  However I thought an "in-language" solution would be best from a maintenance perspective.  Thanks Tomasz for the answer to all who commented.